# Slim Framework 3 RESTful Backend - Serving Images

Tags: php, rest, slim-3

When uploading images on my web application, images are stored in the `/public/uploads/` directory. For those familiar with Slim Framework 3 the `/public/` directory is where `index.php` is stored.

Simply navigating to `http://website.com/uploads/image.png` does not work for I presume it looks for a Slim 3 route?

In order for me to preview images in when navigating to the image, do I have to make a custom route in my REST application?

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: show you'r `.htaccess`-file.

Comment: @jmattheis added my .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I just simply made a new `.htaccess` file in my uploads directory and it worked.

My file contacts the following `RewriteEngine Off`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. (I didn't check code).

```
RewriteEngine On

//Is file not exist then rewrite to index.php 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

// file exist then rewrite to new path and try again with new path.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /public/$1 [QSA,L]
```